# Python merging two CSV files

Tags: python

I have two CSV files. One:

```
s555555,7
s333333,10
s666666,9
s111111,10
s999999,9
```

And two:

```
s111111,,,,,
s222222,,,,,
s333333,,,,,
s444444,,,,,
s555555,,,,,
s666666,,,,,
s777777,,,,,
```

I want to end up with:

```
[['s111111', '10', '', '', '', ''],
 ['s222222', '',   '', '', '', ''],
 ['s333333', '10', '', '', '', ''],
 ['s444444', '',   '', '', '', ''],
 ['s555555', '7',  '', '', '', ''],
 ['s666666', '9',  '', '', '', ''],
 ['s777777', '',   '', '', '', '']]
```

Here's my code:

```
new_marks = get_marks_from_file('assign1_marks.csv')
marks     = get_marks_from_file('marks.csv')

def merge_marks(all_marks, new_marks, column):
    for n in range(len(new_marks)):
        for a in range(len(all_marks)):
            if all_marks[a][0]==new_marks[n][0]:
                 all_marks[a][column]= new_marks[n][column]

                return marks
```

What am I doing wrong? I keep getting:

```
>>> merge_marks(marks, new_marks, 1)

[['s111111', '',  '', '', '', ''],
 ['s222222', '',  '', '', '', ''],
 ['s333333', '',  '', '', '', ''],
 ['s444444', '',  '', '', '', ''],
 ['s555555', '7', '', '', '', ''],
 ['s666666', '',  '', '', '', ''],
 ['s777777', '',  '', '', '', '']]
```

Comment: what does `get_marks_from_file` do? does your second file have any data in it? if not you can just add 4 empty strings to it?

Comment: How are you calling `merge_marks`?

Comment: get_marks_from_file retrivies the csv files

Comment: I meant in what line of code, and with what variables. (Not "calling" as in "what is its name": rather how does the code invoke the function- ). Disregard that, though: I now see you put `merge_marks(marks, new_marks, 1)` above. And the answer is below.

Comment: You appear to have an O(n*m) algorithm there.  You probably should stick one of the files in a dictionary to get it down to O(n+m) - but only if the wait is too long.  Also, it's generally better to use "for x in sequence" rather than "for i in range(len(sequence))".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
                return marks
```

has to be unindented by three levels, to get it out of both for loops and the if statement. Right now it is returning with the first `all_marks[a][0]==new_marks[n][0]` match it finds and never replacing the others.

You also want to return `all_marks` rather than `marks`: In this case, the global variable `marks` happens to be the same and is also changed, but it would fail if you called it with a variable named literally anything else.

The solution is thus:

```
def merge_marks(all_marks, new_marks, column):
    for n in range(len(new_marks)):
        for a in range(len(all_marks)):
            if all_marks[a][0]==new_marks[n][0]:
                 all_marks[a][column]= new_marks[n][column]

    return all_marks
```

Comment: omg omg omg it works. finally after 3 hours of trying to work it out. thank you sooo much